# Texture Transparency Showing Black

Tags: texturing, transparency

I'm attempting to import a model but the transparency of all the textures is showing as an opaque black.

I've tried to change the blend mode to "Alpha Blend" but that hasn't worked for me. Is there something I'm missing?

[image: An example of what the textures look like]

[image: The nodes for the eye texture]

Comment: You have the sockets backwards on your mix shader, but you don't need to do that Mix/TransparentBSDF stuff anymore anyway; just plug the texture alpha into the Alpha socket on the Principled node.

Comment: (Also you need to plug the texture's color into the Principled's Base Color obviously.)

Comment: @scurest THANK YOU! The mix and transparent node stuff was something I copied from a solution given to somebody else haha. In hindsight this seems super obvious.